# Mongoose, returns whole document, not just part of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like my mongoose query callback result from mongodb to only contain a certain part of the document. Right now, the following code returns the whole document, and not just the supposed sliced array portion. Any clues why? In the database, pending actually contains more then 10 elements. Thank you

```
var NotificationsReference = new Schema({

    id             : Number, //fbid
    unRead         : Number,
    pendingSize    : Number,
    pending        : [Notification]

});

NotificationsReference.find({ id: userId}, { pending: { $slice: [skip, 5]}}, function(err, result){
                   if(err || result === null){
                        callback("Failed");
                   }
                   else{
                       callback(result);
                   }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Mongoose API for that:

```
NotificationsReference
    .findById(userId)
    .where('pending')
    .slice([skip, 5])
    .run(function(err, docs){
        console.log(err ? err : docs);
    })
```

Comment: Mongoose 3.x now uses .exec instead of .run: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html